# Summation of$ n$ sub of $i - 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, summation

this is a simple summation but i am not sure how to get from the left side to the right side. Any help would be appreciated. thank you

All I know is that if it is only $n$ sub of $I$, then it will be just $n$ since we are adding $n$ terms like

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} (n_{i} ) = n $$

but how about this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} (n_{i} - 1) = n - k$$

Update:

The above is about graph theory. so if we have a tree of $n$ vertices then the number of vertices in a Forest will be the sum of vertices in each tree. this is the first summation above.

The second summation is for the number of edges in a Forest.

Comment: How are the $n_i$'s defined? And I believe your first summation should have been $k$ according to your logic, as you've added $k$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sum leads to the result of the second as evident from the following.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} (n_{i}-1 ) =\sum_{i=1}^{k} (n_{i} )+ \sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)= n-k $$